# What does (($2 :: fst $1), snd $1) do in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm a beginner in ocaml just need some guidance with the syntax sometimes

```
(($2 :: fst $1), snd $1)
```

I know $2 must be the second token in the line, $1 the first, and fst and snd refer to the first and second component of a pair. I know :: usually indicates to make a list?

And then the overall placement of the parentheses makes me think it's a returning a pair.

But what does this entire line mean, everything taken together?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "first token in the line". Inferring the types, `$1` is a pair that has a list as its first argument, and `$2` is a value of the same type as the list items.

Comment: This isn't valid OCaml, and SO really isn't a suitable forum for "guidance". I would suggest visiting one of the more free-form [OCaml forums](https://ocaml.org/community/) instead, and have a look at [ask] here.

Comment: This is from a .mly file, right? So it's just "a pair composed of a list where the head is the second token and the tail the first part of the first token (that is a pair) and the second part of the first token"
So your first token is a pair of an 'a list and something and your second token is an element of type 'a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax uses the [ocamlyacc rule](https://ocaml.org/manual/lexyacc.html#ss:ocamlyacc-rules) grammar, which is a DSL for writing parsers. Symbols `$N` refer to `N`-th semantic attribute of the defined non-terminal. You can think of them as simple variables, that are bound by the non-terminal pattern expression. So what does `(($2 :: fst $1), snd $1)` mean?

It is a pair, the first constituent is a list `$2 :: fst $1` made from the `$2` and the first element of `$1`, which is itself a pair. And the second part of `$1` makes the second constituent of the resulting pair. E.g., suppose that `$1 = (5,7)` and `$2` is `42`, you will get, `([42;5],7)` as the result of this semantic action.